# Como extrair arquivos blob no firebird?

Tags: firebird, blob

Possuo em uma tabela um campo do tipo BLOB(BLOB SUB_TYPE 0 SEGMENT SIZE 80) onde eu armazeno alguns arquivos binários.
Preciso extrair todos os arquivos armazenados nessa tabela. Através do IBExpert na aba "Data/Form view" é exibido um campo aonde eu posso clicar com o botão direito na opção "Save to file" e salvar esse arquivo normalmente.

Agora, possuo **milhares de registros** arquivos devem ser extraídos.

Existe alguma forma pelo *IBExpert* ou sua ferramenta de script *IBEScript* aonde eu possa extrair todos esses arquivos de uma só vez? Existe alguma outra ferramenta que eu possa fazer isto?

Obs.: Até consegui extrair esses arquivos através da função **ibec_ExtractMetadata** do próprio IBExpert, porém, ele extrai todos os arquivos da tabela eu um só arquivo no formato Hexadecimal, a extensão deste arquivo é **.lob**. Não consegui prosseguir para convertê-lo para o arquivo binário.
Obs2.: Em último caso irei criar um programa através do Delphi para extrair esses arquivos.

Comment: Caso der erro, experimente aumentar o campo varchar de 80 para 1000.
Comigo deu certo

Answer (score 2):

Até onde sei, isso não é possível de fazer para arquivos individuais. O IBExpert possui maneiras de exportar os arquivos blob para um arquivo do tipo .lob. Mas a ideia é que eles sejam utilizados para importação em outro BD e não para utilização individual. Veja os seguintes links:
http://ibexpert.net/ibe/index.php?n=Doc.ImportAndExportUsingIBExpert2
http://ibexpert.net/ibe/index.php?n=Doc.ExtractMetadata#ExtractBlobs

Mas nesse caso você também poderia utilizar o FBExport:
http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq86/

Não existe uma maneira automatizada para exportar esses arquivos assim. Talvez seria melhor que você escrevesse uma aplicação própria em qualquer linguagem para fazê-lo.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer o seguinte, talvez lhe ajude...

Execute o seguinte SQL no IBExpert:

```
select cast(*campo* as varchar(80))
from *tabela*
where *campo* is not null
```

Após você terá os valores em formato texto, então você poderá exportar para um arquivo TXT, Excel, CSV... Como você preferir...